# Blender Internal Noise Texture not showing in Normal channel

Tags: materials, blender-internal-render-engine, shaders

I'm using a Noise Texture (shader) with the Normal influence channel (in BI). And it doesn't show in render. Something does show when I check the Color influence, but not Normal influence. I think I tested every possible setting, with no success. See the attached images for my settings and the render result. The blue tip should show some bump. What am I doing wrong? Maybe it has to do with scale. The tip is just a few millimetres thick, but I also tested different scale values and nothing shows. The noise does show in the preview though.

I'm attaching another image showing the vertices.

[image: Rendered tip][image: Material settings][image: Texture settings][image: Render Layers settings][image: Vertices]

Comment: Can you show the vertices which have the material applied in edit mode?

Comment: Please try 3 tests changing the Influence/Bump Mapping/space ... Object/Texture/View.  I have seen some differences for small pixel bounds.  There are some warning against using this noise for animation. Clouds are suggested in some documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Success! After testing all three of the spaces as mentioned by AtomicBezierSlinger I accidentally discovered what the problem is:

None of the texture shaders (with Normal influence) work with Mesh Lights. It's another limitation of BI obviously. A regular Lamp is needed.

Solved.

Answer (score 1):

You will get different results with the Influence/Bump Mapping/Space setting

[image]